# transform object to array with parent child relationship in lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, typescript, lodash

Is this possible in lodash or any other javascript/typescript way

```
var obj = {
    a: [ {id:1},{id:2},{id:3}]
    b: [ {id:4},{id:5},{id:6}]
    c: [ {id:7},{id:8},{id:9}]
}
// transform to 
var arr = [
{title:a, items:[{id:1},{id:2},{id:3}]},
{title:b, items: [ {id:4},{id:5},{id:6}]},
{title:c, items: [ id:7},{id:8},{id:9}]}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys` for that:

```js
var obj = {
    a: [ {id:1},{id:2},{id:3}],
    b: [ {id:4},{id:5},{id:6}],
    c: [ {id:7},{id:8},{id:9}]
}

var result = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
  return { title: key, items: obj[key] }
})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a highly-readable one-liner for this with lodash and ES6:

```
_.map(obj, (items, title) => ({ title, items }));
```

You can completely avoid `Object.keys()` because [map()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map) works on objects. The callback function gets the object key and the value of that key as arguments. So, you can name them in such a way that allows for object literal shorthand notation, as we've done here with `items` and `title`.

Comment: Arrow function. Return is implicit, which is part of the appeal IMO.

Comment: Older browser maybe?

Comment: No it's definitely the latest browser